# Pass a hex parameter to jQuery function and display as hex--not ASCII

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have a jQuery function that takes a hex parameter. The hex parameter being passed looks like this:

```
\x73\x70\x65\x63\x74\x61\x74\x6f\x72\x20
```

I am able to display this as it is displayed above when using HTML. After passing it to the jQuery function, I attempt to display it like so:

```
$('#divid').text("This should be hex: '" + HEXparam + "' That should have been hex.'");
```

However, instead of displaying the HEX, it displays the ASCII/English translation (in the above case, the word "spectator" is displayed). Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape the slashes in your string before calling `$('#divid').text()`:

```
HEXparam = HEXparam.replace('\\', '\\\\');
```

Note the doubling of the slashes in the above code, this is because a first `\` escapes a following `\`, causing the combination of two of them (`\\`) to be interpreted as a literal "\".

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this after the parameter was passed was not enough. However, I did what you said on the PHP side when generating the parameter and ti worked. It looks pretty convoluted.


        `$spectateHex = '\\\\\\\\x10\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x01\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00\\\\\\\\x00';`

Thanks!